# Hahn-Vitali-Saks theorem: do we need to ask for finite total variations?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, total-variation

In Yosida's functional analysis (p70), we encounter the Hahn-Vitali-Saks theorem, as  also stated on wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali%E2%80%93Hahn%E2%80%93Saks_theorem

In particular, one of the conditions is that for all $n \geq 1$, the complex measures $\lambda_n$ must have finite total variations $|\lambda_n|(S)$.

However, in Rudin's book Real and Complex analysis, in theorem 6.4 (p119) we read that the total variation of a complex measure is always finite (it is even bounded!)

Does this mean that we can drop the condition that the complex measures $\lambda_n$ must have finite total variations in the formulation of the Hahn-Vitali-Saks theorem, as this condition is always satisfied? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Rudin defines "complex measure" he requires the measure to be finite everywhere. That excludes many well-behaved measures, including Lebesgue measure.

I think it's also common to use "complex measure" to simply emphasize that the measure is not necessarily positive, but it might be allowed to include infinite measure cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yosida seems to define complex measure as a set function $\varphi$ that is $\sigma$-additive and such that $|\varphi(B)| \neq \infty$ for all $B$, so I'm not entirely sure if you completely answered the question.

Comment: Moreover, the Lebesgue measure has total variation $\infty$ so the theorem would exclude it anyway.

Comment: That's my point, the theorem excludes Lebesgue measure because it doesn't have finite total variation. Rudin would exclude it by definition. Now, if Yosida defines complex measure the same as Rudin, there is no need to require the hypothesis.

Comment: I don't know if you have a copy of Yosida at hand or even own the book, but I think he defines complex measures on p35. He uses an alternative definition, which I believe is equivalent with Rudin's. This equivalence is an exercise in Folland's real analysis. It sure is confusing haha.

Comment: Yeah, I got to see the book. Immediately after the definition he proves (Lemma 2) that the total variation is always finite. So it doesn't make sense to require the hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was missing something essential!

Comment: Wait a second, the proof you are referring to only applies for real measures.

Comment: True, but you can apply it to the real and imaginary parts of your measure.

Comment: Does that yield an equivalent definition consistent with Rudin's definition? (I.e. the total variation $|\mu|(E)$ is the supremum over the sums $\sum_n |\mu(E_n)|$ where $(E_n)_n$ partitions $E$.)

Comment: I think it does.